# How can I loop through and move certain files using a ksh script (why does my script not work)?

Tags: linux, ksh

I have logfiles in a directory called source, and need to move them to a directory called dest
But only move them if they are between two dates. The dates are in the names of the logfiles in
YYMMDD format, example: a230124b
I have written a script but get some errors and it doesn't work, I'm new to writing KSH scripts so I need some help.

```
# Globals

BEGINDATE = ""
ENDDATE = ""

# Functions

# YYMMDD format
function getBeginDate
{
BEGINDATE = "230123"
}
function getEndDate
{
ENDDATE = "230129"
}


# Example: a220109b
# The date would be January 9th, 2022
# YYMMDD format
# This func will cut logfile name to just the date, and return 1 if it is within the end and begin dates
function checkDate
{
CURRDATE = `echo $1 |cut -c1-6`

if [[CURRDATE == BEGINDATE || CURRDATE == ENDDATE]]; then
   return 1
fi
if [[CURRDATE > BEGINDATE && CURRDATE < ENDDATE]]; then
   return 1
fi
return 0
}

# Main Loop

getBeginDate
getEndDate

for file in ./source/*
do

NAME = `echo $file`

RESULT = checkDate name

if [[RESULT  == 1]]; then
mv $file ./dest
fi

done
```

Errors I am getting:

```
./test.ksh[11]: BEGINDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[12]: ENDDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[44]: getBeginDate[19]: BEGINDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[45]: getEndDate[23]: ENDDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[50]: NAME: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[52]: RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[54]: [[RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[50]: NAME: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[52]: RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[54]: [[RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[50]: NAME: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[52]: RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[54]: [[RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[50]: NAME: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[52]: RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[54]: [[RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? In what way does your script not work?

Comment: ./test.ksh[11]: BEGINDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[12]: ENDDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[44]: getBeginDate[19]: BEGINDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[45]: getEndDate[23]: ENDDATE: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[50]: NAME: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[52]: RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]
./test.ksh[54]: [[RESULT: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: remove the spaces from both sides of the `=` in assignment statements (eg, `x = 3` => `x=3`); when referencing variables you need to add a `$` prefix (eg, `if [[CURRDATE == BEGINDATE ...` => `if [[$CURRDATE == $BEGINDATE...`); add a space between the `[[` (and `]]`) and the conditional tests (eg, `if [[$CURRDATE ...` => `if [[ $CURRDATE ...`); there may be other issues once these chnages are made